.NET 8 Windows Service Example won't start (System.IO.IOException)
I'm trying to create a .NET 8 Windows Service.
Have followed this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service
All is good until I try to start it, Event Viewer reveals it has thrown an I/O error:
Application: dotnet.exe
CoreCLR Version: 8.0.724.31311
.NET Version: 8.0.7
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.
   at System.ConsolePal.SetConsoleOutputEncoding(Encoding enc)
   at System.Console.set_OutputEncoding(Encoding value)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)

Has anyone experienced this and solved?

Where are you running the service from, what is the binpath?

@RossBush I have tried local debug path (\bin\Debug\net8.0\WorkerService1.exe) and publishing single file then using that as binpath, both fail. If I just run WorkerService1.exe at command line it works.

You have to use your published folder profile location path and not the debug path.

Looking at the stack trace:

at System.ConsolePal.SetConsoleOutputEncoding(Encoding enc)
at System.Console.set_OutputEncoding(Encoding value)

You are probably trying to change the Console.OutputEncoding property.
This throws an exception because Windows Services do not have a console or any GUI/TUI system. Windows Services are designed to not have any interaction or visibility at all.
Working with the console requires to open a console handle, which doesn't exist for a Windows service, which is why this exception is thrown instead.
Simply remove all code that includes interaction with the console, which should remove the exception. When it comes to logging from a Windows service, logging to a file instead of the console is a common practice used when it comes to developing Windows services.
